# why are the top five color red red red red red?

Tags: python

> The result is:

```
{'color': 'red', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'green', 'points': 5, 'speed': 'slow'}
alien_number is:30
{'color': 'red', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': 10, 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'yellow', 'points': 15, 'speed': 'medium'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'red', 'points': '15', 'speed': 'fast'}
{'color': 'yellow', 'points': 15, 'speed': 'medium'}
```

> which i think shouldn't be all red the first five.I think the correct sequence should be red yellow 
>       yellow red yellow.why is the perplexing result?

---

```
 import rando

    alien_0={'color':'green','points':5,'speed':'slow'}
    alien_1={'color':'yellow',"points":15,'speed':'medium'}
    alien_2={'color':'red','points':10,'speed':'fast'}
    aliens_1=[]
    color=('red','yellow','green')

    for alien_number in range(30):
    random_num=random.randint(0,len(color))-1  #create a random number in order to get a random color
    if color[random_num] == 'green':
        aliens_1.append(alien_0)  
    elif color[random_num] == 'red':
        aliens_1.append(alien_2)  
    else :
        aliens_1.append(alien_1)  

    for alien in aliens_1[:5]:
        print(alien)
    print("alien_number is:"+str(len(aliens_1)))

    for alien in aliens_1[0:5]:
        if alien['color'] == 'green':
            alien['color'] = 'yellow'
            alien['points']='10'
            alien['speed']='medium'  
        elif alien['color'] == 'yellow':
            alien['color'] = 'red'
            alien['points']='15'
            alien['speed']='fast'
    for alien in aliens_1[0:10]:
        print(alien)
```

Comment: the code has been added to the question. But it needs proper indentation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accidentally changing the entire dictionary instead of the specific alien you want the dictionary to represent.

For now, just add `.copy()` to each time you append an alien dictionary to your random list of aliens.

```py
    if color[random_num] == 'green':
            aliens_1.append(alien_0.copy())
```

In the future, this is probably best handled with classes rather than dictionaries.

When you assign multiple variables to reflect a dictionary, **they don't copy its values**. They are the same dictionary as each other. Changing one changes every other one. Using `.copy()` gets around that, but classes will be more flexible for this type of use and should have fewer 'gotcha' problems.